# How to execute Linux command line in C# Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I  want to execute this command : **iconv -f unicode -t utf8 input.txt > output.txt**

But I got this error : /usr/bin/iconv: cannot open input file `>': No such file or directory

```
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "/usr/bin/iconv";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.Arguments = "-f unicode -t utf8 /tmp/test.txt > Desktop/output.txt";
            Process p = Process.Start(psi);
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you setting it to redirect standard output, and also trying to send the output to a text file?

Comment: just I was fallowing an exemple but I don't use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the `<`, `>` and `|` operators inside a shell. The shell (such as bash) is what actually parses these and performs the redirection. Try this code:

```
...
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "/usr/bin/iconv";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.Arguments = "-f unicode -t utf8 /tmp/test.txt";
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
...
```

I apologize if this code doesn't work properly, I personally rarely program in C#.

You may also be able to just set `psi.UseShellExecute = true`. According to MSDN, this will start the program with the system shell (cmd.exe). This may work for you, although I have not tested.

Best of luck!

Comment: Worked like a charm!